# How to fetch row selection in Smart Table in List Report SAP Fiori app?

Tags: sap-fiori, sapui5

I am using the List Report template to implement an SAP Fiori app. The type of table is `sap.ui.table.Table`

I have added an extension for action to add a 'Download' button and I have set it's `requiresSelection` value to `true`. But I am not able to fetch the table selection.

I receive error

> "Unsupported operation: sap.ui.table.Table#getSelectedIndices must not
>   be called if a selection plugin is applied."

for the below statement:

> var oTable = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getParent().getTable();
>   //which fetches the table inside Smart Table control
>   oTable.getSelectedIndices();

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Inorder to get the selected indices for the above error you are getting

var oTable = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getParent().getTable();

oTable.getAggregations("plugins")[0].getSelectedIndices();

Answer (score 0):

To get the selected index for a sap.ui.table or Grid Table

try this,
var oSmartTable = oEvent.getSource().getParent().getParent().getContent().getTable();

You cannot use getSelectedIndices() directly on table control, so use the below

oSmartTable.getPlugins()[0].getSelectedIndices();

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
oTable._getSelectionPlugin().getSelectedIndices()
```